# Why bitcoin is not working mining take place?

Tags: bitcoin, mining, bitcoind, bitcoin-testnet

I have run the daemon also but its not working
Error is :

```
[2015-03-09 15:28:12] Binding thread 0 to cpu 0
[2015-03-09 15:28:12] Binding thread 1 to cpu 1
[2015-03-09 15:28:33] Stratum connection failed: Failed to connect to 178.209.60
.10 port 5000: Timed out
[2015-03-09 15:28:33] ...retry after 30 seconds
[2015-03-09 15:29:24] Stratum connection failed: Failed to connect to 178.209.60
.10 port 5000: Timed out
[2015-03-09 15:29:24] ...retry after 30 seconds.
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure to understand what your problem is, so I will make some assumptions:
Your bitcoin core is running on the mainnet or the testnet. You use a miner like GUIminer to mine the given bitcoin network.

There are two ways to mine: alone or in a pool (with others). "Stratum" is a protocol used by pools to share mining work to find a new block faster. So here you try to access to an IP address with a stratum call, did you check if this address you're calling can understand your stratum call (i.e. is a mining pool address) ? It seems that this address is just a default website for now: http://178.209.60.10/